# How do you debug your ESP32 applications?

Tags: esp32, testing

So, I asked a question on Hardware Recommendations, looking for a
[Windows USB dongle for LoRa/LoRaWan and BT5/BLE](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11517/windows-usb-dongle-for-lora-lorawan-and-bt5-ble)

I want to develop on ESP32 and to use my Windows laptop as a server to the ESP32's client.

The reason I asked that question looking for a cheap dongle is that I only found a few and they seemed to be very expensive.

Now it occurs to me that I could perhaps have my client ESP332 talk to a server ESP32, which would  seem to be much cheaper than a USB dongle, and have that communicate to my laptop ... perhaps over TTL debug?

How do others generally do this?

Comment: i think that most people will use whatever is available, does the job, and is cost effective, unless they want to use a specific device

Comment: Well, in thsi case, it's ESP32. Do you test ESP32? If so, could you share?

Answer (score 1):

At time of writing, according to the [PlatformIO docs](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/boards/index.html), there is only one ESP32 with on-board debug support - the [ESP-WROVER-KIT-VB](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14917).

It's slightly pricey, but has large 3.5" display. [Here](https://youtu.be/Gb_JFDa0AIo) is a YouTube video of it playing Doom.

[image]

I am also looking at [the JTAG probes which the PlatformIO docs say support ESP32](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/boards/espressif32/esp-wrover-kit.html#debugging), to see if one can be used for other processors, such as ARM (specifically STM32 boards).

Articles such as [this one](https://dzone.com/articles/eclipse-jtag-debugging-the-esp32-with-a-segger-j-l) convince me that the Segger J-link ought to do the trick, and the [J-link EDU](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/models/j-link-edu/) is cheap enough.

Finally, much as I love ESP32, I have to accept that alternatives, such as STM32, have on-board debuggers, if that is a "must have" feature. I do like the look of the [SRM32WB](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32wb-series.html), which has both WiFI and BlueTooth.

I would love to stay with ESP32, especially the [M5stack](https://m5stack.com/) series, which allows plug & play attaching of [hundreds of sensors and motors, etc](https://m5stack.com/), using Grove connectors, not to mention the "wristwatch" version. Alas, the M5stack won't even accept a JTAG probe.

There are a few ESP32 which support Grove connectors, either natively, or via Arduino shield if they have an Arduino pinout. I am examining those, one by one, for debug readiness via JTAG and will update this answer as I make new discoveries - although that is not part of the original question; it's just that my ideal ESP has debug + grove connectors + on-board display, maybe even eInk - obviously, YkMMV.

This question has been dormant for a while, so I thought that I would pay back the community by posting what I have learned so far.